# Storing a POS tagged corpus

Tags: python, nltk

I use NLTK and to POS tag the german Wikipedia with it.The structure is quite simple one big list containing every sentence as a list of word, POS tag tuples example:

```
[[(Word1,POS),(Word2,POS),...],[(Word1,POS),(Word2,POS),...],...]
```

Because the Wikipedia is big I obviously can not store the whole big list in memory so i need a way to save parts of it to disk. What would be a good way doing this in a way so that I can easily iterate over all the sentences and words later from disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pickle`, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle:

```
import io
import cPickle as pickle

from nltk import pos_tag
from nltk.corpus import brown

print brown.sents()
print 

# Let's tag the first 10 sentences.
tagged_corpus = [pos_tag(i) for i in brown.sents()[:10]]

with io.open('brown.pos', 'wb') as fout:
    pickle.dump(tagged_corpus, fout)

with io.open('brown.pos', 'rb') as fin:
    loaded_corpus = pickle.load(fin)

for sent in loaded_corpus:
    print sent
    break
```

[out]:

```
[[u'The', u'Fulton', u'County', u'Grand', u'Jury', u'said', u'Friday', u'an', u'investigation', u'of', u"Atlanta's", u'recent', u'primary', u'election', u'produced', u'``', u'no', u'evidence', u"''", u'that', u'any', u'irregularities', u'took', u'place', u'.'], [u'The', u'jury', u'further', u'said', u'in', u'term-end', u'presentments', u'that', u'the', u'City', u'Executive', u'Committee', u',', u'which', u'had', u'over-all', u'charge', u'of', u'the', u'election', u',', u'``', u'deserves', u'the', u'praise', u'and', u'thanks', u'of', u'the', u'City', u'of', u'Atlanta', u"''", u'for', u'the', u'manner', u'in', u'which', u'the', u'election', u'was', u'conducted', u'.'], ...]

[(u'The', 'DT'), (u'Fulton', 'NNP'), (u'County', 'NNP'), (u'Grand', 'NNP'), (u'Jury', 'NNP'), (u'said', 'VBD'), (u'Friday', 'NNP'), (u'an', 'DT'), (u'investigation', 'NN'), (u'of', 'IN'), (u"Atlanta's", 'JJ'), (u'recent', 'JJ'), (u'primary', 'JJ'), (u'election', 'NN'), (u'produced', 'VBN'), (u'``', '``'), (u'no', 'DT'), (u'evidence', 'NN'), (u"''", "''"), (u'that', 'WDT'), (u'any', 'DT'), (u'irregularities', 'NNS'), (u'took', 'VBD'), (u'place', 'NN'), (u'.', '.')]
```

Comment: Can I somehow append new data to a pickle object without loading it completely into memory? Because and maybe I'm wrong about this I still need to have the whole corpus (probably around 9-10GB) in memory before I can dump it right?

Comment: Actually I would suggest multiple pickle if you're lazy to load but the best solution is still to parse the POS-tagged corpus from textfile and then process it as your parse. Wouldn't that be more portable? Imagine a Java user wanting to use your corpus one day and another day a Ruby user and the next day some Go or whatever new programming language user.

Answer (score 1):

The **proper** thing to do is to save a tagged corpus in the format that the nltk's `TaggedCorpusReader` expects: Use a slash `/` to combine word and tag, and write each token separately. I.e., you'll end up with `Word1/POS word2/POS word3/POS ...`.

For some reason the nltk doesn't provide a function that does that. There's a function to combine one word and its tag, which is not even worth the trouble to look up since it's easy enough to do the whole thing directly:

```
for tagged_sent in tagged_sentences:
    text = " ".join(w+"/"+t for w,t in tagged_sent)
    outfile.write(text+"\n")
```

That's it. Later you can use `TaggedCorpusReader` to read your corpus and iterate over it in the usual ways the NLTK provides (by tagged or untagged word, by tagged or untagged sentence).